# How to pass a string that stores a datatype taken as an input from user into sizeof() operator and obtain the size of the data type?

Tags: c, sizeof

Actually when a datatype, say `int` is stored in a string or a character array,
and the string is passed as an argument to sizeof operator, the program returns the character array size instead of substituting the actual data type that is stored in the string, as an argument.

So is it possible in anyway to substitute the content of the string as an argument instead?

Here's the code in [c](/questions/tagged/c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char s[20];  

        printf("Please enter the data type to find it's size!: ");

        scanf("%s",&s); 

        printf("The size of %s data type in c language is: %d",s,sizeof(s)); 

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: you'll have to scan the string and check it contents - if user wrote int or double or something like that, like __if (! strcmp("double", s)) printf("%d",sizeof(double))__

Comment: This is just impossible, at runtime, there are no *type names*.

Comment: it is a common mistake from people familiar with script oriented languages, but there is no "int" or "double" at runtime, those only exist at compile time. You'd have to make a map with all datatype vs size yourself

Comment: What? You can't store anything in an operator.

Comment: @Nyashes That's not a matter of scripting languages vs compiled languages (all modern interpreter languages compile the source code before execution), but just how `sizeof` is defined which in term is a result of C being weakly typed and historical reasons. Modula, Ada, Pascal, e.g. are aware of the types, C++ provides RTTI, etc.

Comment: There's obviously subtleties, but in this case, there is no rtti and c is not aware of types at runtime in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that’s not possible. There’s no more type information in your program after it’s compiled (of course, there might be debugging information, but I doubt you wanna use that).

One thing you could do, is create a large if statement:

```
// ...
scanf("%s",&s); 

size_t size;
if (strcmp(s, "int") == 0) {
  size = sizeof(int);
}
else if (strcmp(s, "short") == 0) {
  size = sizeof(short);
}
// ... all other types you wanna support
else {
  printf("Did not recognize type %s\n", s);
  return 1;
}

printf("The size of %s data type in c language is: %d ",s,size);
```

This way you retrieve all type information at compile time, store it in your program explicitly and you can therefore access it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `sizeof` is a compile-time operator. Except for VLAs as argument, the operation happens at compile-time, so you cannot modify the argument in run-time and expect it to work magically.

That said, even it would have been possible to evaluate at run-time, it won't make sense, because in a compiled program, the *datatype* does not (need to) exist anymore. Compiler allocates memory (map) based on the data types and there ends the existence of the data types. It does not *live* in a binary so your program has no notion of `int` or `short`.

The best you can do is, have a list of available / allowed type / variables, compare the input for a matched type and then, return the result of applying `sizeof` operator on that variable / type.

**Last but not the least**, `sizeof` produces a result of type `size_t`, you must use `%zu` format specifier to print the result.

Answer (score 1):

No. The `sizeof` operator works directly on types and variables. There is no way to use a variable to refer to a type, and have `sizeof` operate on the type referred to by the variable.

The way you can implement a size query program, is to create an array of supported types, and their sizes, and query that:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    const char *const name;
    const size_t      size;
} type_spec;

const type_spec  known_types[] = {
    { "char",           sizeof (char) },          /* Always 1 */
    { "signed char",    sizeof (signed char) },   /* Always 1 */
    { "unsigned char",  sizeof (unsigned char) }, /* Always 1 */
    { "short",          sizeof (short) },
    { "signed short",   sizeof (signed short) },
    { "unsigned short", sizeof (unsigned short) },
    { "int",            sizeof (int) },
    { "signed int",     sizeof (signed int) },
    { "unsigned int",   sizeof (unsigned int) },
    { "long",           sizeof (long) },
    { "signed long",    sizeof (signed long) },
    { "unsigned long",  sizeof (unsigned long) },
    { "size_t",         sizeof (size_t) },
    { "off_t",          sizeof (off_t) },
    { "time_t",         sizeof (time_t) },
    { "float",          sizeof (float) },
    { "double",         sizeof (double) },
    /* End of array terminator */
    {  NULL,            0 }
};

size_t size_of(const char *name)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; known_types[i].name != NULL; i++)
        if (!strcmp(name, known_types[i].name))
            return known_types[i].size;
    /* Unknown type name, return 0 */
    return 0;
}

void list_all_types(FILE *out)
{
    size_t  i;
    for (i = 0; known_types[i].name != NULL; i++)
        fprintf(out, "sizeof (%s) == %zu\n",
                     known_types[i].name, 
                     known_types[i].size);
}
```

Note that because the type names can contain spaces, I would not use `scanf()` to read them. I would simply have the user specify the type or types on the command line, instead:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t size;
    int    arg;

    if (argc < 2) {
        list_all_types(stdout);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-l") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--list")) {
        list_all_types(stdout);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Usage: %s -h | --help\n", argv[0]);
        printf("       %s [ -l | --list ]\n", argv[0]);
        printf("       %s type [ type ... ]\n", argv[0]);
        printf("\n");
        printf("This program reports the sizes of most basic\n");
        printf("types supported in C.\n");
        printf("\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
        size = size_of(argv[arg]);
        if (!size) {
            fflush(stdout);
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: unsupported type.\n", argv[arg]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        printf("sizeof (%s) == %zu\n", argv[arg], size);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The list in the `known_types` array is not exhaustive, but you can add any types you want to the array trivially, one line per type.
.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a C program, compile it and run it. Something like this:

```
char mytype[100] = "unsigned long long int";
int mysize;

// start the compiler
FILE *f = popen("gcc -x c -o test -", "w");

// generate the program to compile
fprintf(f, "int main(){return sizeof(%s);}", mytype);

// wait for the compiler to finish
mysize = pclose(f);

// run the compiled program and get its exit code
mysize = WEXITSTATUS(system("./test"));

// cleanup - delete the executable
remove("test");

printf("Size of %s is %d\n", mytype, mysize);
```

This is more trouble than it's worth - too many places where it could go wrong (no gcc installed on the system; current directory not writable; etc).